# QGIS doesn't render QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer

Tags: pyqgis, markers, vector-layer, rendering

I'm trying to use QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer to control the appearance of symbols in a vector layer. To create a simple layer (with circles of different colors), I'm using the following snippet:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "RadiusField", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String),
                           QgsField("radius", QVariant.Double)])
vl.updateFields()
categories = []
for idx in range(self.nx):
    for idy in range(self.ny):
        f = QgsFeature()
        f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(self.phalanx[idx,idy,0],self.phalanx[idx,idy,1])))
        punctum = "point_" + str(idx) + "_" + str(idy)
        unique_id = punctum
        f.setAttributes([punctum, 1.0])
        pr.addFeature(f)
        if (idx % 2 == 0) and (idy % 2 == 0):
            symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol.createSimple({'name': 'circle', 'color': 'yellow'})
        elif (idx % 2 == 0):
            symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol.createSimple({'name': 'circle', 'color': 'red'})
        elif (idy % 2 == 0):
            symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol.createSimple({'name': 'circle', 'color': 'green'})
        else:
            symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol.createSimple({'name': 'circle', 'color': 'pink'})
        category = QgsRendererCategory(unique_id, symbol, str(unique_id))
        categories.append(category)
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('CircleColor', categories)
for cat in renderer.categories():
    print("{}: {} :: {}".format(cat.value(), cat.label(), cat.symbol()))
vl.setRenderer(renderer)
vl.updateExtents()
vl.triggerRepaint()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

However, QGIS doesn't render any of the symbols so I'm missing something but not sure what. The categories have been created as `point_N1_N2 :: <qgis._core.QgsMarkerSymbol object at 0xfff...>` so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Aside from a few redundancies in the code, the main problem is that you are passing a field name to the renderer constructor which does not exist in your layer. Instead of `'CircleColor'`, try passing `'name'`. So: `renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('name', categories)`

Comment: OK. I see that my mistake was to think that the first field was a user-defined name rather than a predefined one. Thanks. P.S.: The snippet is sort of a scratch paper for tinkering and therefore the final version should be far more streamlined.

Comment: I should have written 'previously used in the declaration of symbol' rather than 'predefined', which sounds ambiguous.